# Opencv installed however python does not find the package

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, opencv3.0

I have recently installed opencv on my raspberry pi 3 module B to do some vision processing and whilst I was developing this code for said processing I ran my code which is

```
 import cv2
 import numpy as np
 vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 vid.set(10,.05)

def onmouse(k,x,y,s,p):
   global hsv
   if k==1:   # left mouse, print pixel at x,y
      print hsv[y,x]

while(True):
cv2.namedWindow("hsv")
cv2.setMouseCallback("hsv",onmouse);
cv2.imshow('hsv',hsv)
ret, frame = vid.read()
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_green = np.array([75,200,200])
upper_green = np.array([85,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)
cv2.imshow('orig',frame)
cv2.imshow('fff',res)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break


vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

after finishing this I ran my code to see if no errors occurred however I was presented by [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMeX4.jpg)

I was wondering if either I did something wrong with my code or I screwed up in installing opencv. Either way I would be grateful if anyone either had experiences with this same problem or someone has already resolved this issue.

FYI: 
I got the instructions to install opencv from this [site](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/)

As well as sorry for my messy code never really got the the hang of having everything neat as well as my potentially dumb question either way; Thank you for your attention

Comment: Going back to the website you went (http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/), did Step #7 output the desired result? This is to verify your installation of OpenCV.

Comment: Yes it did it , the terminal gave me the exact total but did not give me the root staff number I believe that is because since I might have done it when opencv3 was updated and different resources were either added or removed, am I correct?

Comment: Like emnoor mentioned, you likely have a bad installation. Just try running this in a terminal `sudo apt-get install python-opencv` to install OpenCV version 2.*.*

Answer (score 1):

It appears the name of your script is `cv2.py`. So when you import `cv2`, it imports ***this*** script instead of the cv2 library. Use a different script name.

Comment: Well spotted. I just tried on my end, renaming the same script to `cv2.py`. It gave the same error as OP's. It even created a `cv2.pyc` file at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. However when I renamed this script to vision as show with this image: http://imgur.com/a/WjpTr. It still tells me that the module cv2 is not there, should I attempt to uninstall opencv or maybe I did something wrong in the installation process?

Comment: This error means the OpenCV wasn't properly installed. Or you are not using the proper python version or the environment in which you installed OpenCV. Please check if you are using the right virtualenv and python version (as with the installation guide).

Comment: I followed these procedures twice and still cv2 is still not found do I attempt to reinstall again or do you guys have any good sources to go by by downloading cv2?